# Statistical inference, with MICE and MARS, or simpler?

Tags: regression, probability, distributions, classification, multiple-regression

Given observed results of this [*[nhanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Health_and_Nutrition_Examination_Survey) dataset*]:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c} 
& \text{Age} & \text{BMI} & \text{hyp} & \text{chl} \\ \hline
& 1 & \color{maroon}{N/A} & \color{maroon}{N/A} & \color{maroon}{N/A} & \\ \hline
& 2 & 22.7 & 1 & 187\\ \hline
& \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\ \hline
& 2 & 27.4 & 1 & 186
\end{array}
$$

**How do I provide a confidence float showing where this new observation fits?**

$$
\begin{array}{c|c} 
& \text{Age} & \text{BMI} & \text{hyp} & \text{chl} \\ \hline
& 1 & \color{maroon}{N/A} & \color{maroon}{N/A} & 190 & \\
\end{array}
$$

Currently I'm planning to use:

- [Multivariate Imputation through Chained Equations](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/index.html) for the missing data; and
- [Multivariate adaptive regression splines](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176347963) with an incorporated [generalized linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) to fit new observations

However I'm worried that I'm overcomplicating the solution. **How should this problem be tackled?**

Comment: What do you mean by a confidence float?

Comment: Let's say that nhanes predicts chance of death in next 5 years given those metrics. Then what I want is the probability that this new observation fits that prediction. So a prediction of a prediction. Confidence float as in "68.7369% chance of having 33.6397% chance of dieing in the next 5 years".